# MSVC complains about "DOUBLE" in an enum while Unixen do not

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, yacc

I have [a simple lex/yacc/c program](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC) that I wrote primarily on the mac and am now porting to Windows (CLI). There were only minor conversions required, some time-related calls, handling command line switches, and MSVC complained about some possible null-pointers (that clang should have complained about too) and were easy to fix.

So I'm down to one thing, in my yacc file I have this definition:

```
%token <s> STRING
%token <d> NUMBER DOUBLE SINGLE INTEGER
```

Yacc (bison) turns this into an .h which contains...

```
enum yytokentype {
 STRING = 258,
 NUMBER = 259,
 DOUBLE = 260,
 SINGLE = 261,
 INTEGER = 262,
```

This works without problem on Unixen, but on MSVC it complains that DOUBLE is being redefined. It says the same for the tokens INT and INPUT.

Am I correct in thinking this is a case insensitivity problem? If so, can this be changed in VS? The only things I found online on case insensitivity had to do with file names and that was due to the underlying FS so it seems unrelated. I could add cruft to the token name, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You probably include a header that defines `DOUBLE` as preprocessor macro

Comment: Look in the Output message for the full error message, it tells you where the original definition is located.  Yes, windows.h that's #included without WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN defined is going to provide a typedef.  Name collisions are a chronic problem with enum declarations in C, the standard workaround is to use a short prefix, like "yyDOUBLE".

Comment: @HansPassant - I was not clear on the mention of LEAN_AND_MEAN, but adding that did not help (and it looks like the .h in question is too fundamental). As this is a CLI app, perhaps there is some other header set I should use instead of windows.h?

Comment: `windows.h` contains a lot of names that tend to collide with other headers and which don't have any prefix or namespace. Adding `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before the include decreases the problem but this is not always enough. Another popular solution in to create a separate source file in which handles interaction with the Windows system and to not include `windows.h` in the other files.

Comment: What Piotr said. Don't include Windows crap in your parser. The Windows API is not relevant to parsing. In fact, if you keep all platform-specific code out of the Yacc `.y` file, you can just generate it once, and then compile the same source on all platforms. You only need to run Yacc when the parser changes.

Comment: @Kaz, there is none, it's being imported at the main.c to handle things like command line switches. I had to re-arrange the imports in a couple of places but I cleared it up.